# Amazon SES not sending mail on server

Tags: centos, email-server, amazon-ses

I have configured SES on my server. My product is running in Laravel Framework.

```
MAIL_DRIVER=smtp
MAIL_HOST=email-smtp.us-east-1.amazonaws.com
MAIL_PORT=587
MAIL_USERNAME=A****************A
MAIL_PASSWORD=A***********************************Q
```

Earlier, I was using Laravel's `mail` driver to send mail. It used Postfix to send mails.

I sent a mail from local system after configuring SES SMTP, it worked. But, when I changed the settings on server to send mails from smtp, the mails are still going from Postfix.

I added fake characters in the password.

I stopped Postfix, and the mails stopped going.

What could be the exact issue here?

Comment: sounds like laravel isn't picking up the correct .env file you think it is set in

Comment: I checked that too. It's picking the correct .env file. When I change other variables in .env, my application gets affected.

Comment: Do I need to change something in Postfix?